# Hiding and Unhiding Individual Files Using Applescript

Tags: applescript, hide, show, hidden, tell

I need to write an applescript to hide and unhide specific files.  This is what I have so far, but apparently the spaces in the file name is causing problems.

```
tell application "System Events"
    do shell script "chflags nohidden "/VOLUMES/Works/who/3130026 - Why Onspots.pdf""
end tell
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: For file paths, best is to use the "quoted form of ", like this: do shell script "chflags nohidden " & quoted form of "/VOLUMES/Works/who/3130026 - Why Onspots.pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes inside the shell command, using the backslash '\' character, like so

```
do shell script "chflags nohidden \"/VOLUMES/Works/who/3130026 - Why Onspots.pdf\""
```

Comment: @Sharky: you should really check off his answer as answered then. (Just click on the number thing to the left of the question.